# Prove the equality for the regular $n$-gon

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to prove the equality $g_{k-1}*r_{1}*g^{-1}_{k-1}=r_{k}$ for the regular $n$-gon, using multiplication of permutations?

Here $g_{k}$ is group of rotations by angle $2\pi\frac{k}{n}$, $g_{k}=g_{1}^{k}$ and $r_{k}$ is group of reflections about an axis passing through the $k$ vertex.

I know that $g_{k}=g_{1}^{k}$ and $g_1= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & \cdots & n-1 &n \\
2 & 3 & \cdots & n & 1\\         
\end{pmatrix}$ and $r_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & \cdots & n-1 & n\\
1 & n & \cdots & 3 & 2\\         
\end{pmatrix}$

So I need to write similar expressions for my formula and then multiply these permutations but I dont know how to do this. Can you help?

Comment: Notice that ratations has no fix point,but reflections has fixpoint.just show that $g*r_1*g^{-1}(k)=k$,then it is an reflection.Then show that there is an uniqe reflection fixing a point.(it is easy) then you are done.

Comment: is my hint worked??